# is there any way to search multiple artists tracks from iPod Library at a time .

Tags: ios, ipod, mpmediaquery, mpmedialibrary

I wants to get multiple artists tracks from iPod Library . The following code allow me to get specific artist tracks like -

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [query addFilterPredicate: [MPMediaPropertyPredicate
                                predicateWithValue:@"Lady Gaga"
                                forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
 [query setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

    NSArray *albums = [query collections];
```

is it possible to get multiple artists tracks like **Lady Gaga & Akon** tracks only single query **predicateWithValue** sepearted by ; OR /
 Example-

```
[query addFilterPredicate: [MPMediaPropertyPredicate
                                    predicateWithValue:@"Lady Gaga/ Akon"
                                    forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
```

Please help me how to meet my requirement .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aggregate operator `IN` (e.g. `@"attribute IN %@", aCollection`)and filter the whole `collections` array with an `NSPredicate`:

```
NSArray *artists = @["Lady Gaga", @"Justin Bieber", @"Selena Gomez"];
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingAlbum];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN %@", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, artists];
NSArray *albums = [[query collections] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Hi skyddict, I used your code , but didn't get any result rather than i have tracks of these artists in my device .